# Understanding solution to high school contest problem

Tags: number-theory, contest-math

I came across an interesting problem, for which I do not fully understand the given solution. The problem is from KöMaL (Mathematical and Physical Journal for High Schools), and reads:

> ErWin Layup is the best penalty taker of all times in the basketball league of Nowhereland. Although he missed the very first penalty throw of his career, altogether he has only missed 2020 out of his total of 222222 throws.
> Statisticians in Nowhereland consider a basketball penalty throw interesting if the ratio of successful penalty throws to all penalty throws, calculated immediately after the throw and expressed as a percentage, is a positive integer. (For example, if a player scores 12 out of a total of 40 throws then his last throw is interesting, since 1240⋅100=30∈N+, while the following throw, which is the 41st, cannot be interesting, whether successful or not.)
> What is the minimum number of interesting penalty throws that ErWin Layup may have had?

My approach was that the $1, 2, 4, 5, 10, 25, 50, 100$ throws must be interesting, as these numbers divide $100$. We can also show that if the first, and the last $2019$ throws are missed, then for all other numbers, the throws are not interesting, giving a lower bound of 8 (to show this is simple so I will not detail it here).

The official solution takes a different approach, and shows a lemma stating that for all $1<n \leq 100$, there is a throw which has a success ratio of $\frac{n-1}{n}$. This means there are throws with ratios of $0, \frac{1}{2}, \frac{3}{4}, ..., \frac{99}{100}$, which are interesting, and then we show that there is a construction where these are the only interesting throws, namely the one I gave above. The proof of the lemma divides the cases into two categories:

1. if only one throw was missed until the $n$. one, the $n$. throw is interesting.
2. if at least two throws were missed, there is a point at which the success rate was lower than $\frac{n-1}{n}$, at the beginning, and a point where the success rate was higher than $\frac{n-1}{n}$. Then, there is a "last" throw, the $i \cdot n$, for which the success rate is lower. In order for the success rate to be higher at the $(i+1) \cdot n$ throw, the $i \cdot n + 1, i \cdot n + 2, ..., (i+1) \cdot n$ throws must all be successful. This means only one throw was missing to get the ratio $\frac{n-1}{n}$ at the $i \cdot n$ throw, so the $i \cdot n + 1$ throw has the desired ratio.

My question is the following:

- What is missing from my answer? Why do we need to prove this lemma to get the solution?
- Could somebody please explain to me the part 2. of showing the lemma. The train of thought is not clear to me at all. I can show the same result but through a much more convoluted method (I can detail this if necessary but this is already a long post), so if there is an easier way to see this I would really appreciate the clarification.

Thanks!